# Running exe with parameters from batch script vs running from application

Tags: java, batch-file

I have a very strange issue that I cannot solve. Basically, I have a bat script that runs:

> cmd /c ""C:\Program Files (x86)\XX\YYY\EEE\int.exe"" parameter1
>   parameter2 parameter3

This works as it should and launches **int.exe** which launches two other 3rd party applications based on the parameters.

Then I am also running the same command but from our application based on the below:

> var CMD = "\"\"C:\Program Files (x86)\XX\YYY\EEE\int.exe\"\"";
>
> ...Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c " +CMD + " parameter1 parameter2
>   parameter3 ");

This also works and int.exe is correctly launched with the correct parameters. I can see that when looking in task manager and the command line that the two int.exe launches are exactly the same. However, when the launch is initiated from runtime exec, form our application, only one of the two 3rd party applications that should be started after int.exe is run will start. And I just cannot understand how that is possible. The int.exe is run exactly the same way, why doesn't the second example above also launch the second application? Does anybody know what the difference can be?

Edit: I just saw that if I change **int.exe** to always run as administrator, it will successfully run both applications also from java. This is very strange as I can run the cmd script and it works even though I use a none-admin account on OS level

Comment: Running program directly will save you some time, instead of creating cmd's shell.

Comment: That was very helpful, thank you

Comment: What kind app is your application? What are the other two programs? Particularly, what does the one that fails to run, require in terms of permissions?

Comment: Mine is an application running java. The int.exe launches a third party application that seems to first run xhost and xdpyinfo in order to then launch the second application that never starts. When I look in task manager, it seems its xdpyinfo that fails